# Composition series of a regular module.

Tags: modules, representation-theory, algebras, idempotents

Suppose $A$ is an $k$-algebra with basis ${1,e,s,t}$ and multiplication is given by
$$
       e^2 = e, es = s, te = t, s^2=t^2=se=et=st=ts=0.
        $$

I am trying to find the composition series for the regular $A$-module (as vector space over itself with action given by the multiplication).

It is easy to find that
$Z(A)$ is one-dimensional and that all the nonzero idempotents of $A$ are
$1,e+ps+qt$ and $1-e-ps-qt$ for $p,q \in k$. I was trying to explore the decomposition
$$
A=Ae \oplus A(1-e),
$$
but this gave me nothing. Can you please suggest how to find the composition
series (my goal is actually to find all the simple $A$-modules up to isomorphism, so I decided that this is an equivalent problem).

Comment: @DavidHill I have never claimed that this is an idempotent.

Comment: @DavidHill Nope, I say "It is easy to find that $Z(A)$ is one-dimensional and that all the nonzero idempotents of A are $1,e+ps+qt$ and $1−e−ps−qt$".

Comment: OK. You are right. I misread.